# What can cause "System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out"?

Tags: apex, callout

What else, other than insert/update/upsert/delete, can cause "System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out"?  I've search the debug logs multiple times, and there absolutely is not a DML statement executed between the startTest and the failing callout.

Are there any other commands, or perhaps another callout (even though it's only an inquiry), that can cause this?  Does anyone know how to get around this problem?

Comment: Please share your code and that will take it from a guessing game to a Q&A format.

Comment: Do you have any workflows are getting fired which is sending emails?

Comment: Setting savepoints or rolling back to them, basically any asynchronous calls, there are a great many possibilities here.

Comment: Have you read [this document](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_testing_dml.htm), and made sure you followed the rules? All DML must occur before Test.startTest, Test.setMock should be called immediately after Test.startTest, and your callout should be called immediately after that.

Comment: I'd second @SantanuBoral here... Workflow email alerts (even ones which are triggered in before `startTest()`) will cause this error.

Comment: @AdrianLarson, this is a perfectly legit question the way it is currently phrased... As someone who has also battled with this error mysteriously happening, I would love to see a concise list of all the possibilities that cause this msg to be thrown

Comment: Update: I've just found that the offending operation is Messaging.ReserveSingleEmailCapacity().  I had previously tried using Limits.GetEmailInvocations() and Limits.GetLimitEmailInvocations(), but I found that the former always returns 0 and the latter always returns 10, even after emails have been sent in the current context, so that was useless.

So I guess all I can do is surround the offending calls with if (!Test.IsRunningTest()) ?  Or does anyone know another trick or something I've missed?

Sorry for not posting code but it's voluminous and would give away who my employer is...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is a list of the operations that could possibly count as a `DML` when executed before a callout:

- `Database` [methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm)

  - `convertLead`
  - `delete`
  - `deleteAsync`
  - `deleteImmediate`
  - `emptyRecycleBin`
  - `executeBatch`
  - `insert`
  - `insertAsync`
  - `insertImmediate`
  - `merge`
  - `rollback`
  - `setSavepoint`
  - `undelete`
  - `update`
  - `updateAsync`
  - `updateImmediate`
  - `upsert`
- `System` [methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm%23apex_methods_system_system)

  - `abortJob`
  - `enqueueJob`
  - `movePassword`
  - `process`
  - `purgeOldAsyncJobs`
  - `resetPassword`
  - `schedule`
  - `scheduleBatch`
  - `setPassword`
  - `submit`
- `Messaging` [methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_messaging.htm)

  - `reserveMassEmailCapacity`

**Special Case** - *During tests when object has an email alert*

If using API v38 or earlier during test methods when an email alert is set on the object will also produce this error

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008XHBAA2

Comment: Thanks Adrian.  Actually there's one more under messaging, which is the one I was hitting.

Here's a discovery: within a test run, the system is looking at the real  Limits.getSingleEmailInvocations() and Limits.getLimitSingleEmailInvocations() when trying to send email, even though if you check those values they always return 0 and 10 inside the test, respectively.  Since test instances typically only allow 10 emails, this is a serious issue for any code that generates emails.

Comment: I've made this post a wiki, in case anything was missed. Feel free to add any methods that are not included already.

Comment: Thanks for this.  After a callout, I was calling a simple Database.executeBatch that contained no explicit DML, inside a class that contained no explicit DML.  Took me a day to track this down and (kind of) understand. The basic response of 'Dont do any DML before a Callout' isnt really clear enough for me. Is there any documentation that simply calling methods such as Database.executeBatch will count as a DML?